# Watch variable in ng-repeat in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive called `advancedMode` that can be placed on a `table` like this:

```
<table advanced-mode>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="user in users">
      <td>{{ user.id }}</td>
      <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now I'd like to add code to my directive so that it watches `$scope.users`. But the tricky part is, is that I don't know what variable names people will use in the `ng-repeat`. In this case it's `$scope.users`, but it might very well be something like `$scope.orders`.

So is there a way to get the variable nam that is used in the `tr` tag with my directive?

Currently my directive looks like this:

```
.directive('advancedMode', [function() {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        options: '=',
        rows: '=',
    },
    link: function ($scope, $elem) {
        // get list from ng-repeat in tr tag and watch that for changes
    }
}]);
```

Comment: Is it really neccessary to know that? Could you just pass the `users` into your directive directly like in the @MattWay answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what you mean by

> But the tricky part is, is that I don't know what variable names people will use in the ng-repeat

but can't you simply pass the list variable into your directive like so:

```
.directive('advancedMode', [function() {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        list: '=advancedMode',
        options: '=',
        rows: '=',
    },
    link: function ($scope, $elem) {
        // the list is now in $scope.list
        console.log($scope.list);
    }
}]);
```

Then just add the list in your markup:

```
<table advanced-mode="users">
```